# How to manage ruby workers processes for start, stop and restart?

Tags: ruby, bash, zeromq, worker

I have many workers like this :

```
Client.rb                      Worker.rb
 |                              |
 |- Client1.rb <=>          <=> |- Worker1.rb   
 |- Client2.rb <=> Proxy.rb <=> |- Worker2.rb
 |- Client3.rb <=>          <=> |- Worker3.rb
```

The inter-process communication is done with ZMQ

Actually, i start all process in background with this bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash

ruby Proxy.rb &
ruby Worker.rb &
ruby Client.rb &
```

For example, this script force me to use "kill" command for stop all processes ... It's not fun.

How can i start, stop, restart all process like a service ?

Comment: what are the commands for start/stop/restart. Cant we put them in bash scripting. Is this you looking for?

Comment: yes, right. Otherwise, I have to manually find the PID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a process monitoring system. There are many solutions to this, for example

- monit
- bluepill
- god

I've used god most recently. With god create a configuration file that defines each worker, how to stop/start it and when it should be restarted automatically (eg if it is using too much memory)

As long as you can setup your scripts to drop a pidfile at a predictable location then it's pretty easy. For example if your god config file contained

```
ROOT = "/folder/containing/files"

3.times do |num|
  God.watch do |w|
    w.group = "workers" 
    w.name = "worker-#{num}"
    w.dir = ROOT
    w.start = "ruby ./Worker.rb --pid tmp/pids/worker.#{num}.pid "
    w.pid_file = File.join(ROOT, "tmp/pids/worker.#{num}.pid") 
    w.behavior(:clean_pid_file)

    w.start_if do |start|
      start.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.interval = 5.seconds
        c.running = false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

then `god start worker-0` (or stop, restart) would act on the first worker, whereas `god start workers` would start all 3 workers (and start them again if they crashed). You would need to change your script to write its pid file to the location indicated by the --pid argument

Answer (score 0):

For **shell control** over the PID-s et al, there is a nice glitch from Tom Dysinger:

```
./sample server   & server=$!    
./sample worker0  &  node0=$!
./sample worker1  &  node1=$!
./sample worker2  &  node2=$!
./sample worker3  &  node3=$!

... alowing finally to

kill $node0 $node1 $node2 $node3 $server
```